# Combobox values depending on other combobox values

Tags: c#, combobox

Using visual c# I have 5 combobox's. I want all to have numbers 1-5, but when one is selected, all others disappear. I.e. if I select number 3 from combobox 1, none of the others have the number 3. Any ideas? I would post code but pretty stuck for ideas in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Add your sample code

Comment: Will the comboboxes be enabled as you go or is there the ability to start selecting from any of the 5 comboboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ComboBox programmatically on your Parent ComboBox like:

```
    private void ComboBoxParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numComboBoxes = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < numComboBoxes; i++)
        {
            ComboBox comboBoxChild = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            comboBoxChild.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 21 * i);//Position on the Form
            comboBoxChild.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);//Size of the ComboBox

            this.Controls.Add(comboBoxChild);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     private void ComboBoxParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int numComboBoxes = 5;
           ComboBox SelectedCombo = sender as ComboBox;
            for (int i = 0; i < numComboBoxes; i++)
              {
                ComboBox comboBoxChild = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
                comboBoxChild.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 21 * i);
                comboBoxChild.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
                this.Controls.Add(comboBoxChild);
                comboBoxChild.SelectedIndex=SelectedCombo.SelectedIndex;
               }
        }
```

Comment: Please suggest an edition of my answer before copying, editing and publishing it yourself.